# File is Still in Use Error 32 How can I free it?

Tags: file, delphi, delphi-2009, file-in-use

I am uploading a file via the following code.

After a successful upload I am attempting to Delete the file but I am getting a 32 - File in use error.

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this file in use error? The following code is uploading the file, but not releasing it when done..

```
var
  HTTP: TidHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  PostData: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  ResponseStream: TStringStream;
  Delete : Boolean;

begin
  ResponseStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  HTTP := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
  SSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

  try
    SSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    HTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000; //30 seconds
    HTTP.ConnectTimeout := 30000; //30 seconds
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
    HTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol];
    HTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
    PostData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

    PostData.AddFormField('username', 'demo');
    PostData.AddFormField('password', 'demo');
    PostData.AddFormField('action', 'upload');
    PostData.AddFormField('accountno', 'demo');

  PostData.AddFile('uploadedfile', FileName, GetMIMETypeFromFile(FileName));

  HTTP.Request.ContentType := PostData.RequestContentType;
  HTTP.Post('http://uploadsite.com/ex/exampleAPI.asmx/Process', PostData, ResponseStream);

  if AnsiContainsStr(ResponseStream.DataString, 'Done') then
    Delete := True;

finally
  SSLIOHandler.Free;
  HTTP.Free;
  ResponseStream.Free;
end;

if Delete then
  if DeleteFile(BFlashFileName) then
    ShowMessage('Deleted')
  else ShowMessage(BFlashFileName+' not deleted, error = '+
               IntToStr(GetLastError));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the `Clear` method of your `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` instance before attempting to delete the file. If you don't need it anymore, freeing it will also amount to same (i.e. `PostData.Free`). Currently, it looks like you're leaking your `PostData` variable.

While `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` is clearing its Fields collection, the file stream created by the `AddFile` method will be destroyed closing the file's handle.